# Apply jQuery function to first x results in selector?

Tags: jquery

When I call this function every image on the page page its src replaced with the images data-src attribute:

```
function showAllImg(param) {    
    $("img").each(function (index, element) {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
    });
}
```

How can selectively apply this function? I want to swap the src for the first three images if you click trigger-3. I want to swap for the first 6 if you click trigger-6. Later on I might make it so clicking other divs will change the src for a specific image. Basically I want lots and lots of different ways to apply this function to images.

```
$('.trigger-3').click(function(){
    $(".selector img").slice( 3 ).showImg();
});

$('.trigger-6').click(function(){
    $(".selector img").slice( 6 ).showImg();
});

function showImg(param) {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
}

<div class="trigger-3">Change first 3</div>
<div class="trigger-6">Change first 6</div>

<ul>

            <li>
                <img data-src="img/1.jpeg" src="whatever.jpeg" />
            </li>
                <img data-src="img/2.jpeg" src="whatever.jpeg" />
            </li>
                <img data-src="img/3.jpeg" src="whatever.jpeg" />
            </li>
                <img data-src="img/4.jpeg" src="whatever.jpeg" />
            </li>
                <img data-src="img/5.jpeg" src="whatever.jpeg" />
            </li>
                <img data-src="img/6.jpeg" src="whatever.jpeg" />
            </li>
                <img data-src="img/1.jpeg" src="whatever.jpeg" />
            </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please add HTML code

Comment: You have an `index` in `jQuery.each()`. Why not use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the good way to achieve what you want. First of all, `.slice` is the way to go, but the first parameter is the index **to start** while the second is the index **to end** (excluded).

So, your slice should look like that :

```
$(".selector img").slice(0, 3);
```

Then, your `showImg` is a function, not a jQuery method, so you can't call it like that. So you either create the jQuery method with `$.fn.showImg` or use `.each()` and pass your function like that :

```
$(".selector img").slice(0, 3).each(showImg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `index` in `jQuery.each()` like in the below example:

```
function showAllImg(param) {    
    $("img").each(function (index, element) {
        if (index < 3) {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
        }
    });
}
```

This will replace the source for the first 3 elements.

With the use of `jQuery.slice()` (see Karl-André Gagnon answer) you are actually reducing the set of elements before going through the `each` loop which will be better in terms of performance.

**Edit**: regarding your edit, you could do better with a data attribute (this way you don't need an event listener for each *trigger* element):

**HTML**:

```
<div class="trigger" data-slice="3">Change first 3</div>
<div class="trigger" data-slice="6">Change first 6</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
    $(".selector img").slice($(this).data('slice')).each(showImg);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your function you could use your index in the foreach loop:

```
function swapImages(howMany) {    
    $("img").each(function (index, element) {
        if(index < howMany) {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });
}

$('#buttonToSwap').click(function(){
    swapImages(3);
});
```